# android google oauth signin redirect url

Tags: java, android, oauth, xamarin, google-plus

I'm developing an Android app that uses Google+ signin. I searched in the net and this guide in stackoverflow is really helpful:

[Google Account login Integration for android Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520180/google-account-login-integration-for-android-xamarin/25766256#25766256)

Now, i miss one step.

I created an oauth web client id in the google developers console (not android client id) using the redirect url, like the guide said, `http://abcd.com/xyz.aspx` , and works. But i can't use it!

So i tried `http://localhost` (doesn't work) and google urls like `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto` but i can't even set it in the textbox when i create the client id because is invalid url format (it wants the `http://`, and yes, it doesn't work as well).

I haven't got a web application with an aspx view to redirect, i'm developing an android app. So what could it be my redirect url?

Thanks for any help!